# Degree of the restriction of $f: M\to N$ to the boundary of $M$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, solution-verification, stokes-theorem

I attempted a problem from *An introduction to differential manifolds* by Jacques Lafontaine, but was wondering if I had made a mistake anywhere. It is question 20 from Chapter 7, pg. 321.

> Let $M$ be a compact, orientable, $(n+1)$-dimensional manifold with connected boundary $\partial M$, and let $f$ be a smooth map from $M$ to a compact, orientable manifold of dimension $n$. Show that $\deg(f|_{\partial M})=0$.

My attempt: Let $f:M\to N$ be smooth where $M$ is as above and $N$ is a compact, orientable $n$-dimensional manifold. Since $M$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional, $\partial M$ is a compact, orientable $n$-dimensional manifold. Let $\omega\in \mathcal{A}^n(N)$ be an orientation form on $N$. Then $f|_{\partial M}^*\omega \in \mathcal{A}^n(\partial M)$ and, in particular, $d(f|_{\partial M}^*\omega)=0$ since $\mathcal{A}^{n+1}(\partial M)=\{0\}$. Hence
$$\deg (f|_{\partial M})\int_N\omega = \int_{\partial M}f|_{\partial M}^*\omega = \int_M d(f|_{\partial M}^*\omega) = 0$$
where the second equality is by Stoke's Theorem. However, $\int_N\omega\not=0$ since $\omega$ is an orientation form on $N$, so we have that $\deg(f|_{\partial M})=0$ as desired.

My apologies if I am making any major misconceptions or wrongfully over-simplifying the question. My main concern is that I am missusing Stoke's Theorem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your solution is perfect. Only i'd call it a "volume form", not "orientation form".

Comment: @BennyZack: No, it's not.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @BennyZack, Ted helped me to find a solution; check out his answer to see the mistake and the comments to see the fix. Also, out of curiosity, are volume forms and orientation forms the same thing? We've only talked about orientation forms in my course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof is not quite right. You need a form defined on all of $M$ in order to apply Stokes's Theorem. By your logic, any time you integrate a form on the boundary you would get $0$. So what is the easy fix here? How do you get an $n$-form on all of $M$?

Comment: Hi--thank you very much for your response. If I take $M\xrightarrow{\pi}\partial M \xrightarrow{f|_{\partial M}} N$ where $\pi$ is by projection, then $(f|_{\partial M}\circ \pi)^*\omega$ would be an $n$-form on $M$, correct? Then, $d((f|_{\partial M}\circ \pi)^*\omega)= (f|_{\partial M}\circ \pi)^*(d \omega)$, but $d\omega = 0$ since $\mathcal{A}^{n+1}(N)=\{0\}$. So, we get that $\deg(f|_{\partial M}\circ \pi) = \deg(f|_{\partial M})\deg(\pi) = 0$. But since $M$ and $\partial M$ aren't of the same dimension, I don't think $\deg(\pi)$ would make sense-perhaps this is not what you mean.

Comment: There need not be a map $\pi\colon M\to\partial M$. Why are you assuming that? Reread the hypotheses. You start with a map $f\colon M\to N$.

Comment: Right, thanks. Is the idea that we can write $$\int_{\partial M} f|_{\partial M}^*\omega = \int_{\partial M} f^*\omega = \int_M d(f^*\omega)$$ and then the integral on the right is still zero since $d(f^*\omega) = f^*(d\omega) = 0$ since $\mathcal{A}^{n+1}(N)=\{0\}$ as I wrote above?

Comment: Now you've got it!

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for your help!